Newton's method to solve for $f=ax^2-x+1=0$

Let $\{x_k\}$ be sequence generated by Newton's Method for solving
$ax^2-x+1=0$, where $0<a\leq\frac{1}{4}$. Suppose $x_0<\frac{1}{2a}$.
Show $x_k<x_{k+1}<\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4a}}{2a}$

Let$f(x)=ax^2-x+1$, so $$f'(x)=2ax-1$$
Hence, I derived $$x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{ax_k^2-x_k+1}{2ax_k-1}=\frac{ax_k^2-1}{2ax_k-1}$$
$$\begin{align*}
x_{k+1}-x_k&=\frac{-ax_k^2+x_k-1}{2ax_k-1}
\end{align*}$$
Monotonicity:
Since $2ax_k-1<0$ and $-ax_k^2+x_k-1<0$ for $x_k<\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4a}}{2a}$, $x_{k+1}>x_k$. However the conclusion only restricted to certain value of $x_k$.
Bounded:
Let $x=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4a}}{2a}$.
$$\begin{align*}
x_{k}-x=\frac{ax_k^2-2arx_k+r-1}{2ax_k-1}
\end{align*}$$
Since $2ax_k-1<0$, it remains to show the numerator is negative. However from the graph below, numerator is never negative.
I am stuck at proving boundedness, is my method wrong? Any hint will help!

Thanks!
Edit: Update my progress, add more details, and specify the part I am stuck at.

Please check this (if I am right): If $x_0 = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4a}}{2a} < \frac{1}{2a}$, then $x_k = x_0, \forall k$.

@RiverLi, if $0<a<\frac{1}{4}$, then $x_k=x_0$. However we can't determine if it is true if $a=\frac{1}{4}$.

Yes, perhaps the condition is $x_0 < 1/(2a)$ and $x_0 \ne \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4a}}{2a}$.

Fact 1. Let $0 < a \le \frac14$ be given. Consider the recurrence relation: $x_0 < \frac{1}{2a}$ and $x_0 \ne \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4a}}{2a}$
and $x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{ax_k^2 - x_k + 1}{2ax_k - 1}, \, k=0, 1, 2, \cdots$. Then
$$x_k < x_{k+1} < \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4a}}{2a}, \, k = 1, 2, \cdots.$$

Proof of Fact 1.
We use the Mathematical Induction.
The statement is true for $k = 1$.
Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4a}}{2a} - x_1
 &= \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4a}}{2a} - \left(x_0 - \frac{ax_0^2 - x_0 + 1}{2ax_0 - 1}\right)\\
 &= \frac{a}{1 - 2ax_0}\left(x_0 - \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4a}}{2a}\right)^2\\
 &> 0,
\end{align*}
and $x_2 = x_1 - \frac{ax_1^2 - x_1 + 1}{2ax_1 - 1} > x_1$, and
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4a}}{2a} - x_2
 &= \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4a}}{2a} - \left(x_1 - \frac{ax_1^2 - x_1 + 1}{2ax_1 - 1}\right)\\
 &= \frac{a}{1 - 2ax_1}\left(x_1 - \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4a}}{2a}\right)^2\\
 &> 0.
\end{align*}
Assume that the statement is true for $k$ ($k \ge 1$).
By the inductive hypothesis, we have
$x_{k+2} = x_{k+1} - \frac{ax_{k+1}^2 - x_{k+1} + 1}{2ax_{k+1} - 1}
> x_{k+1}$, and
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4a}}{2a} - x_{k+2}
 &= \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4a}}{2a} - \left(x_{k+1} - \frac{ax_{k+1}^2 - x_{k+1} + 1}{2ax_{k+1} - 1}\right)\\
 &= \frac{a}{1 - 2ax_{k+1}}\left(x_{k+1} - \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4a}}{2a}\right)^2\\
 &> 0.
\end{align*}
Thus, the statement is true for $k+1$.
We are done.
